# How do I trigger CSS animation on react element that has changed due to state change?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to recreate this effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA2Eh.jpg
Currently I'm rendering an  with the "src" based on the state.
Like this

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import home_food from "../images/home/home_aji_de_gallina.jpg"
import food from "../images/menu/entry/causa.jpeg"

import { useState } from "react";

const TestBoks = styled.div`
    background-color:red;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: ${props => props.opacity || 0.6};
    transition: ease-in-out;
`;
const TestContainer = styled.div`

    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
`;
const WholePage = styled.div`   

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;

    img{
        width: 100px;
        transition: ease-in;
    }
`

const pictures = [home_food,food]

const Test = () => {

    const [Picture, setPicture] = useState(pictures[0])

    function setNewPicture(index_number){
        setPicture(pictures[index_number])
        
    }

    return (

        <WholePage> 

        <TestContainer>
            <TestBoks key={Picture[0]} onMouseEnter={() => setNewPicture(0)}/>
            <TestBoks key={Picture[1]} onMouseEnter={() => setNewPicture(1)}/>
        </TestContainer>  

        <img src={Picture} alt="ononon" />
           
        </WholePage>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

And it ends up looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS12k.jpg

However, it ignores the animation I described in the styled.div

**So my question is, how do i trigger an css animation on a render caused by a state change?**

**If there is a better way to achieve the effect linked in the Imgur, please share that as well**

Answer (score 0):

You should use useEffect in order to listen for state changes. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Also, don't forget to import: `import { useEffect } from 'react';`

```
const Test = () => {

  const [Picture, setPicture] = useState(pictures[0])
  const [newPicture, setNewPicture] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setPicture(pictures[newPicture])
  }, [newPicture]);

  return (

      <WholePage> 

      <TestContainer>
          <TestBoks key={Picture[0]} onMouseEnter={() => setNewPicture(0)}/>
          <TestBoks key={Picture[1]} onMouseEnter={() => setNewPicture(1)}/>
      </TestContainer>  

      <img src={Picture} alt="ononon" />
         
      </WholePage>
  );
};
```